# Counterexample for connected graph

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

> Let X be connected and $f : X → Y$ is continuous. Show that the graph, ${(x, f(x)); x ∈ x} ⊂ X × Y$, is connected, and give a counterexample to show that the converse is not true.

I think the first question can be shown by constructing a vector-valued function. But I'm stuck on the counter example. Could you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X=[0,\infty),$ $Y=\mathbb{R}$ and $$ f(x) =\begin{cases}\sin (1/x) & x>0 \\ 0 & x=0\end{cases}$$

Then $f$ isn't continuous, yet for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $x\in (0,\varepsilon)$ such that $f(x)=0$. Thus, $(x,f(x))\in B((0,0),\varepsilon)$ in $X\times Y$. However, the graph of $f|_{X\setminus \{0\}}$ is clearly connected, since this function is continuous. We get that the graph of $f$ is connected.

Comment: Notably, any path-connected graph of a function on $X \subseteq \Bbb R$ must correspond to a continuous function

Comment: I think this example is not right. $(x,f(x))$ is not a connected graph if we include $0$ into domain

Comment: @XLZ it is connected (in the more general sense), but not path-connected

Comment: It is *the* classic example of a space which is connected but not path-connected.

Comment: I see. I always mix them up....Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Connected means cannot break the graph into 2 separated sets. Path-connected means we cannot join (0,0) with $sin(1/x)$ by a continuous path.

Comment: Join $(0,0)$ with $(x,\sin(1/x)$, but yes.

Answer (score 1):

Example: let $X = [-1,1] \times [-1,1]$ and $Y = \Bbb R$.  Define $f:X \to Y$ by
$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
x & x \geq 0 \text{ and } y \geq 0\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
$$
$f$ is not continuous (for instance over the line $x = 1$ in $X$), but the graph is path-connected and therefore connected.

Comment: Thank you very much!